# .net core mvc application error after publishing to iis

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to host .net core mvc application in iis. When I publish I get below error -

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
>   following locations were searched:  /Views/Home/Index.cshtml 
>   /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: @SeM - I was missing views in the "publishOptions' as mentioned by Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `Views` folder to publishing. In you `project.json` file you have section `publishOptions` with subsection `include`. Add relative path to "Views" folder here

```
{
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      ...
    ]
  },
}
```