# Cannot find views only after publishing ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

After installing .NET 8, I can no longer publish .NET 7 and run them. These are ASP.NET Core 7 MVC projects and they run fine in debug mode through Visual Studio, but they do not run as soon as they are published to IIS.

The error is that the site cannot find the views. I have tried solutions as described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/25157) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087588/net-core-mvc-application-error-after-publishing-to-iis) and other places, including modifying the `.csproj`, etc. I am on Visual Studio 17.9.1, the application is written in .NET 7, and until .NET 8 was installed, ran without issue.

[image: Here]

This is my publish profile (unchanged since it last worked), I have added

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

All views are set to content, and so on. I've tried adding new views, checking output, etc. What am I missing?

Here is my `.csproj` and my `program.cs`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>%24/BCC/yyy/yyyMvc</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>{4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>xxx</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>.</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
   <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.102.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="7.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilers" Version="4.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="4.8.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="tinysort" Version="3.2.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectBase\ProjectBase.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
using yyyMvc.Classes;
using yyyMvc.Middleware;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using NLog;
using NLog.Web;
using ProjectBase;
using System.Data;

Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

try
{
    // *********************************
    // BUILDER
    // *********************************
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Host.UseNLog();

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    
    // Session
    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<SessionManager>();
    builder.Services.AddSession();

    // app settings
    builder.Services.Configure<ConfigWeb.AuthenticationSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationSettings"));
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDbConnection>(db => new SqlConnection(
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetValue<string>("Test") ?? 
            throw new Exception("Missing connection string")) { });
    builder.Services.Configure<ConfigWeb.LoggingSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("LoggingSettings"));
    builder.Services.Configure<ConfigWeb.SiteSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("SiteSettings"));

    // *********************************
    // APP
    // *********************************
    var app = builder.Build();

    // Error is first middleware
    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    // Get authentication prepared, with sessions
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    // Logging middleware, must be after Cookies / Session, must be before MVC routing
    ConfigWeb.LoggingSettings loggingSettings = new ConfigWeb.LoggingSettings();
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("LoggingSettings").Bind(loggingSettings);
    if (loggingSettings.DataViewLogging)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<LoggingHandlerMiddleware>();
    }

    // No map MVC
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.Run();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // NLog: catch setup errors
    logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: does the views included in the resulting build though? check the folder manually, are they there or simply not brought along the compiled executables. sometimes you have to do a [manual copy as workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765877). kinda silly though..

Comment: Could you please check if there's no .NET 8 version co-exist then the issue persisted?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you if I had a version of .Net 8 prior, but I don't believe so. I replayed all the events on my machine and found that it was instead the fact that I upgraded Visual Studio Pro to 17.8.3. I continued updating all the way up to 17.9.1, but it didn't resolve it, as well as trying all the modifying csproj and cshtml copying solutions. After several hours, I found by creating some new projects and comparing what works and what doesn't, the fix that works for me is that all nuget packages have to be uninstalled and re-installed - even the same version of the packages works, but they must be completely removed and re-added. I'm not sure exactly what the root cause was but re-installing all packages for all affected solutions worked for me.