# How to compile a .NET 8 web site and include the razor views?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 web project. I have encountered the issue where it can find the views:

> The view '~/Features/HomePage/Index.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched: ~/Features/HomePage/Index.cshtml

I can solve this problem by installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`, adding `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` to my `Startup.cs` and by adding:

```
<CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
```

to my `.csproj`.

My question is: why do I need to do this? Without this NuGet package, what is the expected way to include my Razor views and have them deploy?

Comment: Pls allow me to post below to show my ideas better. And correct me if I misunderstood your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can't reproduce your issue in my side, I created a new .net 8 webapp(razor pages) via the template in VS2022, and then create Razor Page in `Pages/Features/HomePage/Index.cshtml`, then running the app allows me to visit `localhost:port/Features/HomePage/Index` and see the view page.

And about `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`, we can [see document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) here that this is used for `.cshtml` runtime compilation so that real-time changes of views will appear on page refreshing. About `CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory`, we can [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-8.0) that

> Typically, Razor files aren't required for a published app if they
> participate in compilation at build-time or publish-time.

Therefore, lacking of `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` shouldn't be the direct cause for your issue. The workaround you used might doing something to make sure all the cshtml content are included when build and publish. The real issue should be some reason causing the SDK failed to find your cshtml.

I have several ideas here. First of all, we can create a new .net 8 web app project and add the cshtml to test if the issue still exist, if yes, it might relate to SDK. If not, I'm afraid there's some configuration causing the issue. You mentioned that you are adding configuration in `Startup.cs` but in .net 8, we should only have `Program.cs` by default, I'm not sure if you are having an old project and upgrade it to .net 8, in this scenario, I think we'd better to check whether there's any configuration to make the app ignore the cshtml file you put in that folder. Maybe we can review Program.cs, Startup.cs, csproj file, launchSetting.json.

If none of them is helpful, please share a minimal sample here for reproducing issue and further investigation.

Comment: It might result from some unknow problems, I found another question which ended in an unexpected way.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/78047038/14574199